# Using Threadpool in a Subscription based windows service c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool, subscription

I am implementing a windows service which will be subscribing to an external data source. Whenever there is some update in the external data source it will activate an eventhandler lets say OnDataReceived method. The number of updates received from the data source could be huge at a particular time of day. For example, in evening, within 30-40 mins I could get ~50K event handler calls. This event handler gets the data as XML and does some processing onxml before saving it to Database.

I am trying to figure out if so many eventhandler call in small time window will overwhelm my service by creating too many threads or the .Net framework will manage the number of threads running in parallel. If this can cause issues, so I am planning to use ThreadPool to put the request on a thread in the EventHandler thus reducing the time request spends in EventHandler method code.

So looking out for suggestions from fellow coders if I need to worry about thread management at all in my scenario. If yes, do you see any problems with the approach I am planning to take or if you can suggest some better approach to handle it.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: 28 events per second is not particularly huge, a modern processor can handle *millions*.  Hammering a dbase engine with 28 updates per second, well, that's a different kettle of fish.  Something you can easily test.

Comment: If you can use async/await to communicate with database use that. For Ado.Net see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx. Entity Framework v6 also implements async access. If the xml processing is really that time consuming maybe you can use batch processing the xml using Plinq: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx